# how to set output of sql query to a veriable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am using 2008 R2 ,I want to set output of "Select Colname from tablename" to one veriable ie. @resultvar ,so further I can use it in stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in a single value, it is as simple as:

```
DECLARE @resultVar    nvarchar(50)  -- or whatever
SELECT @resultVar = Colname FROM tablename -- with appropriate filtering
```

If you're needing to get this out from a stored procedure, then you need to look into OUTPUT parameters:

```
CREATE procedure MyProcedure
    @resultVar    nvarchar(50)    OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @resultVar = Colname FROM tablename -- with appropriate filtering
```

If you're using SQL to run the procedure, you can then use:

```
EXEC MyProcedure @var OUTPUT
```

Obviously, if you're using a framework such as Entity Framework, then you need to use whatever that framework provides; but, that's a totally separate question.

Be aware that if multiple rows come back from tablename, you will only get the value from the first row. If it is more complex than this, please expand the original question.

Comment: Thank u for your help but problem is @resultvar doesn't get result of query. so help me on how can I get result of query to  resultvar

Comment: I'd recommend expanding the question then, with sample data and what you'd expect @resultvar to contain. That way it will be easier to help you get the answer you're wanting.

Comment: I want set stored procedure variable  = output of query

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example using an OUTPUT parameter on a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple code like this:

```
DECLARE @resultvar AS VARCHAR(64) --or any other type you need
SELECT @resultvar = ColName FROM TableName WHERE --filter on table
PRINT @resultvar
```